# How do i fix this expression and value error in vb?

Tags: vb.net, expression

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Move_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
        PictureBox1.Location.X = (197 + TrackBar1.Value)
    End Sub
End
```

That is my visual basic code.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more please? I'm unsure about what you want, here.

Comment: You should assign a new point, `PictureBox1.Location = New Point(x, y)`

Comment: I want PictureBox1 to get moved by TrackBar1

Answer (score 1):

You don't set `.Location.X` or `.Location.Y`. If you want to set just one then you set `.Left` or `.Top`. If you want to set both, you set `.Location` with a `Point`.

```
PictureBox1.Left = (197 + TrackBar1.Value)
```

The reason that you get the error you do is because `Location` is type `Point` and that is a value type.  When you get a value-type property you get a copy of the value, not a reference to the value.  That means that any change you make is made to the copy, not the original.  As such, if your code was allowed, you'd be setting the `X` property of a copy of the `Point` stored in the `PictureBox's` `Location` property.  That would have no effect on the `PictureBox` and be utterly useless.  If you want to change value-type properties like that then you need to get the property value into a variable, change the variable, then assign the copy back to the property:

```
Dim pt = PictureBox1.Location

pt.X = 197 + TrackBar1.Value
PictureBox1.Location = pt
```

Setting the `Top` and `Left` properties avoids this two-step as it is done internally.

Comment: If it's not working then you did it wrong. If you don't tell us what you did, what hope have we got of working out what you did wrong? You need to ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes EXACTLY what you expect, EXACTLY what you did and EXACTLY what happened.  This shouldn't need explaining but it is explained in the Help Center of this site, which you ignored when prompted to take a tour when you joined.  I suggest that you take the time to take that tour and read a few more relevant pages too. It will help you write better questions and get better answers.